# Getting SyntaxError with async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have the following the following code I am trying to run with node.js:

`ethereum-block-by-date.js`

```
module.exports = class {
    constructor(web3) {
        this.web3 = web3.constructor.name === 'Web3' ? web3 : { eth: web3 };
        this.checkedBlocks = {};
        this.savedBlocks = {};
        this.requests = 0;
    }
.
.
.
    async getEvery(duration, start, end, every = 1, after = true) {
        start = moment(start), end = moment(end);
        let current = start, dates = [];
        while (current.isSameOrBefore(end)) {
            dates.push(current.format());
            current.add(every, duration);
        }
        if (typeof this.firstBlock == 'undefined' || typeof this.latestBlock == 'undefined' || typeof this.blockTime == 'undefined') await this.getBoundaries();
        return await Promise.all(dates.map((date) => this.getDate(date, after)));
    }
.
.
.
```

And
`getBlockNumber.js`

```
const EthDater = require('ethereum-block-by-date');
const { ethers } = require('ethers');
const url = "node url";
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(url);

const dater = new EthDater(
    provider
);

let blocks = await dater.getEvery('hours', '2018-11-15T00:00:00Z', '2018-11-22T00:00:00Z');

console.log(blocks);
```

When I run `node getBlockNumber.js`, I get the `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` referring to the `let blocks = await dater.getEvery()` function call.

If `getEvery()` is defined as `aync` in `ethereum-block-by-date.js`, then why is it returning this SyntaxError? When I remove `await` from `dater.getEvery()` it returns a `Promise` object.

Comment: You can only use await **inside** an async function. Your code is not **inside** async getEvery.

Comment: Yes, this resolves the issue. I have posted it in the answer below, which no longer returns the SyntaxError. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved when I put the `await dater.getEvery()` inside an `async` function and then call the function:

```
async function getBlocks() {
    let blocks = await dater.getEvery('hours', '2018-11-15T00:00:00Z', '2018-11-22T00:00:00Z');
    console.log(blocks);
}

getBlocks();
```